# How to pull data from a PHP file with AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, json, http, formatting

Okay having a problem with my php file.  I'm using AngularJS to pull some data from a php file,
here is my angular code.  It is the source code from W3schools.  Great code but I'm having some trouble, as promised:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
    {{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("customers.php").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data.records;
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So, my question is how to I format the php to read this

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
      "City": "Berlin",
      "Country": "Germany"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados",
      "City": "México D.F.",
      "Country": "Mexico"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Antonio Moreno Taquería",
      "City": "México D.F.",
      "Country": "Mexico"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Around the Horn",
      "City": "London",
      "Country": "UK"
    },
    {
      "Name": "B's Beverages",
      "City": "London",
      "Country": "UK"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Berglunds snabbköp",
      "City": "Luleå",
      "Country": "Sweden"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Blauer See Delikatessen",
      "City": "Mannheim",
      "Country": "Germany"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Blondel père et fils",
      "City": "Strasbourg",
      "Country": "France"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Bólido Comidas preparadas",
      "City": "Madrid",
      "Country": "Spain"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Bon app'",
      "City": "Marseille",
      "Country": "France"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Bottom-Dollar Marketse",
      "City": "Tsawassen",
      "Country": "Canada"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Cactus Comidas para llevar",
      "City": "Buenos Aires",
      "Country": "Argentina"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
      "City": "México D.F.",
      "Country": "Mexico"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Chop-suey Chinese",
      "City": "Bern",
      "Country": "Switzerland"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Comércio Mineiro",
      "City": "São Paulo",
      "Country": "Brazil"
    }
  ]
}
```

All this is form W3schools.com I'm trying to reproduce the php file for a homework assignment but can figure out how to format the php to read this.  PLEASE HELP.  Also, here is a link to the w3school example that I'm using https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp it is under the JSON example.  This example was great but it only helped with the angular part not the php section and I can't find in any info.

Thanks

Comment: Do you even understand what `$http.get` is doing? If not read up on that

Comment: What I'm having problems with is getting data with the $http.get.  From what I understand it is similar to an ajax request.  I'm having problems with the backend

Comment: So what have you done with your PHP so far?

Answer (score 0):

Put it in your file php

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','project');
$sql="SELECT * FROM ...";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$rows = array();
if($result){
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print '{"records":' .json_encode($rows) ."}";
}else{
    echo mysqli_error();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
      <?php
         $dbhost = 'HOSTNAME';
         $dbuser = 'DBUSERNAME';
         $dbpass = 'DBPASSWORD';
         $dbname = 'DATABASENAME';
         $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);

         if(! $conn ) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
         }
         $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_name';
         $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

         if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
               $rows[] = $row;
            }
            print "{'records':" .json_encode($rows) ."}";
         } else {
            echo "0 results";
         }
         mysqli_close($conn);
      ?>
```